# how to route in SpringRouteBuilder to a dynamic uri contained in Camelhttpquery?

Tags: dynamic, apache-camel, uri

I am pretty new at Apache Camel and do not find an elegant way to solve my problem.
I am getting an incoming request as follows:

> servlet:/services?http:///services?param1=value1&param2=value2…

I want to dynamically route to

> http:///services?param1=value1&param2=value2…

When the uri servlet:/services is "detected" (from)

I can extract the endrequest from header("CamelHttpQuery") but I don't figure out how to use it for the forwarding. Here is the implementation I tried but it doesn't work:

```
public class Routes extends SpringRouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {   
        this.from("servlet://{{path.directory.service}}?matchOnUriPrefix=true").beanRef("filterPolicy", "canAccess")
            .recipientList(this.header("CamelHttpQuery")).removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is toD method for dynamic endpoint
http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html

F.e. I have this working code for dynamic uri

```
  <setHeader headerName="customerId">
    <ognl>request.body.customerId</ognl>
  </setHeader>
  <setBody><constant></constant></setBody>
  <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
      <constant>GET</constant>
  </setHeader>            
  <toD uri="http4://localhost:9292/score/customer/${header.customerId}?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it was someting i was considering but i am having problem using it with Java DSL. if you have any idea how to implement it. the point is that the uri i want to forward to is contained in CamelHttQuery. i would really appreciate any help. thanks in advance.